# Modify text color in Facepile?

Tags: facebook

I've been trying to change text color of Facepile because my site has black background and thus the black text of Facepile doesn't show up.

I tried setting "color" parameter of "metadata_with_margin", but that didn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Use the attribute **colorscheme="dark"**.  Then the Facepile text will be white.

(The only two choices for colorscheme are "light", which is the default, and "dark".)